# javascript code to change the background color onclicking more buttons

Tags: javascript, matrix, background-color

the background color should change on clicking the button there is one rule the button should be created by matrix as shown bellow.the error is red is the only output comming while clicking any button

```js
var currColor = 5,
  flag = 1;
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black'];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  document.write('<input type="button" onclick="change()" id="btn" value=' + colors[i] + ' style="background-color:' + colors[i] + ' ;"></input>');
}

function change(i) {
  var colorsName = document.getElementById('btn').value;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colorsName;
}
```

Comment: `document.write` is a bad idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: And using the same id in multiple buttons is also a bad idea, because `.getElementById` can find the first element only. Pass `this` to the function, and read the color from `this.value`. To change the `document.write` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `id`s that elements have should be unique in the whole document.

So instead working with the `document.getElementById()` function you should work with the `target` of the event:

Also you shouldn't use the `onclick` aatribute rather then use the `addEventListener` method of the HTML element.

Then `document.write` shouldn't be used. Use DOM manipulation instead

And if you use a button, I recommend it to be a `button` element instead of an `input[type=button]`. But that is debatable.

```js
function change(e){
    var colorsName = e.target.value;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colorsName;
}
var currColor = 5, flag = 1;
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black'];
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.innerText = colors[i];
    button.value = colors[i];
    button.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    
    button.addEventListener('click', change)
    document.body.append(button)
}
```